# How to find the Vector form of a Plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

I attempted to solve the equation but it appears the final value is still wrong

**My Attempt:**

$2x - 4y + 6z = 12$, set $y = 1$ and $z = 0 \implies 2x -4(1) + 6(0) = 12 \implies 2x = 12 + 4 \implies x = 8$

Comment: Show us your attempt, please.

Comment: updated @SeanRoberson

Comment: Hint: If $t=1$ and $s=0$, $\vec x$ should be a point/vector in the plane.

Comment: You didn't take the $(6,0,0)$ into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct way of doing this is
$\left[\begin{array}.x \\ y \\ z\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}.\frac{12+4y-6z}{2} \\ \;\;\;\;y \\ \;\;\;\;z\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}.6+2t-3s \\ \;\;\;\;\;t \\ \;\;\;\;\;s\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}.2 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]t+\left[\begin{array}.-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]s+\left[\begin{array}.6 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right].$

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is what you're asking, but in terms of vectors, a plane is the set of points that are perpendicular to a fixed vector called the normal vector $n:=(x,y, z)$Thus,  using the fact that if vectors $v:=(v_1, v_2, v_3),w:= (w_1, w_2, w_3),w$ are orthogonal then a plane is described as the set of points $(a,b,c)$ satisfying $$<(x,y,z), (a,b,c)>=0$$, for <,> being the dot product.
This last leads to ,

$$ax+by+cz=0 $$, the standard equation of the plane.